# Convert Json to array Angular2 js with type script

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have the json data i want to convert to an array with the specified keys.

```
[
  {"id":1,"url": "http://test.com"},
  {"id":2,"url":"https://ad.com/"},
  {"id":3,"url":"https://ad12.com/"},
  {"id":4,"url":"https://ad12.com/"}
]
```

## Code:

```
 http.get('', { headers: ''})
     .map(var response => response.json();
     return response.map(d => {
     return new class(d.url);
    }););
```

I need only url key values.

```
Output:`["http://test.com", "http://ad.com", "http://ad12.com"]
```

`

Comment: well, why not hold it in model and apply map over it?

Comment: I have tried but not able to achieve it .

Comment: Show what you've tried please.

Comment: @echonax I have tried the above mentioned code.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
http.get('', { headers: ''})
    .map(response => {
        return response.json().map(d => {
            return new class(d.url);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

if using lodash then ..

```
var urls = _.map(yourArray, 'url');
```

or ES6 and lodash ..

```
let urls = _.map(yourArray, 'url');
```

or ES6 and no lodash ..

```
lets urls = yourArray.map((obj) => {
    return obj.url;
});
```

or ES5 and no lodash ..

```
lets urls = yourArray.map(function (obj) {
    return obj.url;
});
```

Comment: More idiomatic ES6 would be `map(({url}) => url)`.